# Adding custom value in a LINQ join

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists with me:

- FXCashFlow [contains - amount, paymentdate, TradeId, Currency]
- FXTrades [Contains - TradePreferences, TradeId]

What I need to have in the return class is:

- Return Object [Type, amount, paymentdate, TradeId, Currency, TradePreference]

Where Type = "Fx", as the data is fetched from Fx class.

For Return Object, I am using a LINQ JOIN like this:

```
 var list = _fxCashflow.GetAll().Join(_fxTrade.GetAll(),
             outerKey => outerKey.TradeId,
             innerKey => innerKey.TradeId,
             (CashFlow, Trade) => new
             {
                //"Fx", <- This line gives error
                CashFlow.TradeId,
                Trade.TradeReference,
                CashFlow.PaymentAmount,
                CashFlow.CurrencyCode,
                CashFlow.PaymentDate,
                CashFlow.CashflowTypeCode
             }
            );
```

I need to insert "Fx", because this data will be concatenated to a class where this "Fx" will identify the records returning from cashflow class.

How can I insert a custom value in this returning object? Or if there's any other way to do this?

Much Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to insert it like this instead:

```
         (CashFlow, Trade) => new
         {
            Type = "Fx",
            CashFlow.TradeId,
            Trade.TradeReference,
            CashFlow.PaymentAmount,
            CashFlow.CurrencyCode,
            CashFlow.PaymentDate,
            CashFlow.CashflowTypeCode
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it make more sense to introduce an actual `Fx` class rather than using a string identifier?

```
public class Fx
{
    public int TradeId { get; set; }
    public string TradeRef { get; set; }
    public decimal PaymentAmount { get; set; }
    ...
}

(CashFlow, Trade) => new Fx
{
    TradeId = CashFlow.TradeId,
    TradeRef = Trade.TradeReference,
    PaymentAmount = CashFlow.PaymentAmount,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store this information in enum and use it inside your anonymous object or you can define a new property for the anonymous object.